# Error, using multiple WHERE in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having error trying to access mysql data, using multiple WHERE clause in preparedstatement. This is the code that generate sql exception( parameter index out of range ( 2 > number of parameters, which is 1 );

```
"SELECT Arrived_time, Closed_time FROM ? 
WHERE (\"Year  = ?\n) AND (\"Month = ?\n) AND (\"Day = ?)"
```

and I entered the three paremeters.  Is there a better way?

Comment: I would be surprised if you were allowed to use a parameter for the table name - and why do you have quotes at the start of `Year`, `Month` and `Day`?

Comment: I entered four paremeters, not three.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, nor does it explain why you're trying to use a parameter for the table name.

Comment: This question is missing code, and the query as it stands can't work, as Jon points out. And you indeed can't use a parameter for the table name. Can you add some more detail and information?

Comment: Please show the PHP code where the parameters are filled in to where the query is executed.  Using ? as the table name should be okay in this manner, provided SQL is not required to do the substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you need to specify your table name and use correct quoting:

```
"SELECT `Arrived_time`, `Closed_time` FROM TABLENAME
WHERE (`Year`  = ?) AND (`Month` = ?) AND (`Day` = ?)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing quotes when naming the columns `"Year"`, `"Month"`, and `"Day"`:

```
"SELECT Arrived_time, Closed_time FROM ? 
WHERE (\"Year\"  = ?\n) AND (\"Month\" = ?\n) AND (\"Day\" = ?)"
```

In your version, the database will be looking for a column called something like `"Year  = ?\n) AND ("`

Comment: Quotes aren't valid field identifiers in mySQL, though, so this will still fail. So will the `?` where the table name should be

Comment: I will use table name instead, paremeter.

Comment: i will try the examples. Can someone kindly write correct code for that.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Oh, you're right, I'm used to Postgres, which uses `"Identifier"` where MySQL uses `\`Identifier\`` (I also use MS SQL, which uses `[Identifier]` :|)

Comment: It really annoys me that there's not a standard for quoting identifiers! :P

Comment: @user1707592 - if it works, please accept (tick) the solution you found most useful.